# [angular2][ngModules] how to call component from other module?

Tags: angular

After update angular to rc5 i have a small problem.

I start rewrtie my application to modules [ngModules].

And i have a small problem, I have two different modules, but module1 need to call a directive (component) from other module.

For now i doing that, but didn't worked ...

AppModule (module 1):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpModule }     from '@angular/http';

import { SimCardsModule } from './+sim-cards/sim-cards.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    SimCardsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

AppComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare let $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

and in template

```
<sim-cards> loading </sim-cards>
```

now i have sim-cards.module (module 2):

```
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HttpModule }     from '@angular/http';

import { SimCardsComponent } from './sim-cards.component';
import { SimCardsService } from './sim-cards.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SimCardsComponent
    ],
    imports: [

        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [SimCardsService],
    entryComponents: [SimCardsComponent],
    bootstrap: [SimCardsComponent]
})
export class SimCardsModule {

}
```

and sim-cards.component (module 2):

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {SimCardsService} from './sim-cards.service';
import {IfEmptySetDefaultPipe} from '../pipes/if-empty-set-default.pipe';
import {IsInternalSimCardPipe} from '../pipes/is-internal-sim-card.pipe';
import {ClientNumberSimCardPipe} from '../pipes/client-number-sim-card.pipe';
import {OperatorIdSimCardPipe} from '../pipes/operator-id-sim-card.pipe';

declare let $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'sim-cards',
    templateUrl: 'sim-cards.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['sim-cards.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    pipes: [IfEmptySetDefaultPipe, IsInternalSimCardPipe, ClientNumberSimCardPipe, OperatorIdSimCardPipe]
})
export class SimCardsComponent implements OnInit {
...
}
```

How to do it in right way ? Do i need to import a component (sim card) in appmodule ? of in appcomponent ?

Or i do something wrong ??

In browser i get only string, loading... no error in console.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Export `SimCardsComponent` from the SimCardsModule. Only exported components are usable in the importing modules.

```
@NgModule({
    exports: [SimCardsComponent],
    ...
})
export class SimCardsModule {
```

The [NgModule documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) is a must-read.

Comment: thanks man !! i already read doc, before add question... i mismatch this section !!